# Batch: Read string from file, write to another file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file which will read and replace specified lines/strings of text within another file.

Example:

I have a file located at `\\company.local\netlogon\data.txt` containing the following:

```
JohnDoe=157 JoeSmith=104 JoeBloggs=514
```

I want to read one those strings after the equals sign, so basically as a log on script I could search for the line containing `%username%`, then read the number after the equals sign into a variable such as `%number%`.

So if `JohnDoe` were to log on, it would search for his name and read `157`.

I would then like to be able to search for a string in another file and write to a specific string, so it would search for `Extension=` and write `157` after it.

Something like `Extension=%number%` which would then read into the file as `Extension=157`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have edits to make please make them minor edits, I have edited it for you to the SO standard :)

Comment: @BaliC: That's rushing into editing for you. :) The OP must still have been in the process of brushing up the post when you started fixing it. Sometimes you just need to take patience and wait a little till it steadies before starting the clean-up. :)

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah I guess I came across the post just as they had posted it, and started editing it :)

Comment: @Antony - For reading files look at `FOR/?`, for searching look at `findstr /?` and for writing look at redirecting like `echo Extension=123 >> myFile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you have the file formatted, but if you have each entry as a new line this will work.

```
set extlist=P:\ath\to\extensionlist.txt
set userdata=P:\ath\to\directory\%username%.txt

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (%extlist%) do if /I %%a.==%username%. set ext=%%b

ren %userdata% %username%.txt.bak
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (%userdata%.bak) do if /I %%a.==Extension. (echo Extension^=^%ext%>>%userdata%) else (echo %%a^=^%%b>>%userdata%)
del /Q %userdata%.bak
```